# Why do I need gimptools to build makedev?

Tags: compiling

I've been following [this](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~okeefe/p2b/buildMin/buildMin.html#toc3) tutorial, and I've found myself needing to compile makedev. However, when I try

```
ROOT=/mnt make install
```

in the source directory (makedev-20110824), I get:

```
gimptool-2.0 --install-script misc/xcf-png.scm
make: gimptool-2.0: Command not found
make: *** [misc/icon.png] Error 127
```

As I understand it, [makedev](http://archive.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs-museum/4.1/LFS-BOOK-4.1-HTML/appendixa/makedev.html) is a utility that automatically populates the /dev directory, whereas [gimptools](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/libgimp/libgimp-gimptools.html) are used for image manipulation.

Why do I need gimptools to build makedev? Is there a way I can build it without gimptools and still expect to make it through the tutorial without much trouble?

P.S.

Also in case it is relevant, I'm running a reasonably minimal Debian install on VirtualBox.

Comment: Have a look at the `Makefile`, maybe it explains what it's trying to do (and maybe there's a target that doesn't depend on `misc/icon.png` while still doing what you want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you got the right makedev ? I found the multiple versions of makedev:

- The one available at [sunsite.unc.edu](ftp://sunsite.unc.edu/pub/Linux/system/admin/) which the tutorial mentions. There is makedev-1.6.1, which is written in C and makedev-2.2, which is a shell script.
- makedev-20110824 (google lead me to [this sourceforge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/makedev/)). It would appear that this is not maintained much.

As for the `gimp-tool` invocation, it looks like the author of the makedev-20110824 wanted an 'icon' whose original (in gimp XCF format) was converted to a png during the `make`. I don't understand why the author would put an icon for a system utility like makedev which is unlikely to be launched off a desktop environment.

Also, I'd like you to checkout [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/), considering your interest in the tutorial. That tutorial is quite old (2000) and you might face many problems putting the pieces together (which might be a good thing if you enjoy it).